# accessing current_user in mailboxer mailer notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionview, mailboxer

I'm trying to print user name into a mail template which has been created via rails g mailboxer:views.

Whenever I try to call the method, raises an "method or variable current_user not found", although public methods as User.**id** do prints.

Here's the view

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You have a new reply from <%=  current_user.name %>: <%= @subject %></h1>
    <blockquote>
      <p>
        <%= raw @message.body %>
      </p>
    </blockquote>
    <p>
      Visit your inbox for more info.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the model

```
class ConversationMessage
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include Sanitizable

  # Attributes
  attr_accessor :sender, :body, :conversation


  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :body

  # Sanitize contenteditable attributes
  sanitize_html :body

  def save
    if valid?
      ApplicationRecord.transaction do
        # In a transaction, as mailboxer performs many inserts
        sender.reply_to_conversation(conversation, body)
      end
    end
  end

  def mailbox_full_name
    full_name
  end
end
```

And the mailboxer.rb

```
Mailboxer.setup do |config|

  #Configures if you application uses or not email sending for Notifications and Messages
  config.uses_emails = true

  #Configures the default from for emails sent for Messages and Notifications
  config.default_from = Settings.env.mailer.sender

  #Configures the methods needed by mailboxer
  config.email_method = :mailbox_email
  config.name_method  = :mailbox_full_name

  #Configures if you use or not a search engine and which one you are using
  #Supported engines: [:solr,:sphinx]
  config.search_enabled = false
  config.search_engine = :solr

  #Configures maximum length of the message subject and body
  config.subject_max_length = 255
  config.body_max_length = 32000
end
```

There's also a concern which is used for the custom methods mailbox_email and mailbox_name

```
module DeliveryMessage::Mailboxable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    acts_as_messageable

    def mailbox_full_name
      full_name
    end

    #Returning the email address of the model if an email should be sent for this object (Message or Notification).
    #If no mail has to be sent, return nil.
    def mailbox_email(object)
      email
    end
  end
end
```

UPDATE: It is the same issue than this one. [Show username on Mailboxer inbox in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671728/show-username-on-mailboxer-inbox-in-rails#20833386)

And it is solved the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have access to controller helpers from the mailer view.

Instead you need to use attributes of `@message` object.

```
<h1>You have a new reply from <%= @message.sender.name %>: <%= @subject %></h1>
```

Comment: Hi, @MikDiet

It eneded up like this:

`<h1>You have a new reply from <%= @message.sender.full_name %> to <%= @subject %></h1>`

being `full_name` a method in the model.

Thanks for the feedback.